# Can I get a Canadian student visa with a passport with less than 6 months on it?

Tags: canada, study

Can I get a Canadian student visa with a passport that is valid for less than 6 months? My study lasts 2 years and has a co-op term.

Comment: I am not sure it makes a difference but which country and how long do you plan to be in Canada for? Can you please edit that into the question.

Comment: Most importantly, is your course of study less than six months.

Comment: @DJClayworth It's 2 years and I get a diploma at the end. It also has a co-op term.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to renew your passport before applying.

[This Canadian Government page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/passport-travel-document.html) says:

> **Visiting, working and studying temporarily**
>
> We can’t issue you a work permit, study permit or visitor record that is valid past the expiry date of your passport.